# Visual Studio Code compiles with npm, node.js but does not show GUI interaction on localhost:42000 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python3, nodejs, npm, visual-studio-code

I just successfully installed `npm 6.12`, `Node.js` version `12.13` on my `Ubuntu 19.04`. 
I also successfully compiled a project using `Visual Studio Code`. It is my first time using VS and I have been trying to build this project with partial success and I don't understand why, despite the project compile successfully, it does not build.

Below the organization of the project tree:

[image: organization-tree]

This is the outcome of the terminal after a launch `npm start` where I successfully compile but not build:

[image: compile]

Finally I can confirm that this is partially working because the `localhost:4200` is actually working as is possible to see from the print screen below:

[image: localhost]

**What I tried so far**

I tried many different options from launching `npm` in any possible way from the terminal line embedded in VS, but also using Linux command line.

I went through the entire project and installed all missing libraries such as: `scipy`, `matplotlib` and `pandas` and `numpy` but still nothing on the localhost side.

In addition I have tried to start and stop several times `npm` but no luck.

**The Problem**

I should be able to interact with a graphical user interface but what I see is only the `localhost:4200` page without any interaction and only red-ish colored.

What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Not being an expert on Node, I would still say the CLI output looks good... you sure your code  is not broken in any way? Tried earlier version of Node? You have a default route set to `root` ?

Comment: @Smurfz87, thanks for reading the question. Yes all path are correctly set and that is confirmed by not giving any errors after running it.

Comment: and what does the chrome dev console tell you? any errors? No errors running does not mean everything is configured correct, just that you have not triggered anything that would print an error.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the console is perfectly fine

Comment: I am posting [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jlbk0ov9n5pf8yt/AAAJ6Fj5dSzrhs1WdqfOE9jKa?dl=0) a small video of the problem. Hopefully this could be of help to better understand.